# How to find the sum of $n$ terms in the sequence - $ \dfrac{1}{1.2.3}+ \dfrac{1}{2.3.4}+\dfrac{1}{3.4.5} + \cdots+ \dfrac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math, pattern-recognition

> How to find the sum of $n$ terms in the sequence - $ \dfrac{1}{1.2.3}+$
> $\dfrac{1}{2.3.4}+\dfrac{1}{3.4.5} + \cdots+ \dfrac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}$?

I added a few first terms like, $ \dfrac{1}{6}, \dfrac{5}{24}, \dfrac{9}{40},\dfrac{7}{30}$.I just couldn't figure out any patterns.

Is there any generalized formula to get the sum of $n$ terms or what kind of approach should I go for to solve problems like this?

Comment: Do you know about partial fraction decomposition?

Comment: Please use \cdot to get a centered dot for multiplication, so 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 gives $1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3$.  Periods can look like decimal points.